# How to get SAML response string after successful login from spring security saml

Tags: spring, spring-security, saml, spring-saml

I am using spring security saml extension for sso in my application. I am able to successfully integrate with adfs. Now I need the exact encoded SAML response we get from adfs to be passed to webservices downstream. How to get that SAML response string?

Answer (score 4):

**If your SAML token is encrypted:**

You can extend default **SAMLAuthenticationProvider** and override authenticate method. Inside this method you can get the complete SAML Response as follows:

```
SAMLAuthenticationToken token = (SAMLAuthenticationToken) authentication;
SAMLMessageContext context = token.getCredentials();
 try {

            String assertion = XMLHelper.nodeToString(SAMLUtil.marshallMessage(context.getInboundMessage()));
            System.out.println(assertion);
        } catch (MessageEncodingException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**If your SAML token is not encrypted, you can use this:**

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
SAMLCredential credential = (SAMLCredential) authentication.getCredentials();
Assertion assertion = credential.getAuthenticationAssertion().getParent();
```

Comment: I got a compile error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from XMLObject to Assertion

Answer (score 2):

See chapter 9.5 in the [manual](https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security-saml/1.0.x/reference/html/configuration-sso.html), it discusses how to keep the Assertion in the original format using the `releaseDOM` flag and how to extract it (in the same way as Agam writes).