# Retrieve Entire SAML Response in Spring Security SAML Extension

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-sts, spring-security-saml2

I have a Spring Boot application that is setup as a Service Provider. My end goal is to be able to call the [AWS STS Assume Role with SAML](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/API_AssumeRoleWithSAML.html) service to generate AWS temporary credentials on behalf of the user with the SAML response used to initially authenticate users of my application.

I found this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48656560/how-to-get-saml-response-string-after-successful-login-from-spring-security-saml). With that answer I am able to get only the assertion, not the entire response. From my testing, the AWS API call linked above wants the entire response, not just the assertion piece.

I used this [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/saml-message-decoder/mpabchoaimgbdbbjjieoaeiibojelbhm) to view the SAML response. When I include everything (outline below)

```
<samlp:Response>
   ...
   <saml:Assertion>
       ...
   </saml:Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

The AWS STS Assume Role with SAML works. The other related question's answer only provides me the

`<saml:Assertion>...</saml:Assertion>`

block and the AWS STS Assume Role with SAML fails.

So my question is how do I get the entire SAML Response XML object back in a controller of my Spring Boot application?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know any direct way in spring-security-saml, but maybe you could try to  implement your own SAMLProcessingFilter ie simply extending the existing one and overriding the method attemptAuthentication().

Principle:

- In this method, you have access to the response returned from the IdP and post back to the SP (at least in a Redirect-POST profile)
- You probably have a way to extract what you need from the httpRequest
- Then you can store (session, ThreadLocal variable, ...)
- And finally you delegate the authentication process to the parent (by calling super.attemptAuthentication())

`

```
@Override
public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
    if ("POST".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
        String samlResponse = request.getParameter("SAMLResponse");
        System.out.println("Original SAML Response (base64 decoded) : " + new 
        String(Base64.getDecoder().decode(samlResponse), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    }
    return super.attemptAuthentication(request, response);
}
```

`